# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::attach()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Buenas estoy utilizando la versión de Laravel 5.8 y estoy intentando duplicar un producto con sus relaciones que salen de 3 tablas.

Modelo producto:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey='id';
    protected $fillable = ['order'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'id');
    }

    public function galerias()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Galeria', 'product_id');
    }

    public function combinations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Combination', 'product_id');
    }

    public function variations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Variation', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Modelo Combination:

```
class Combination extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'combinations';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'id');
    }
}
```

Modelo Variation:

```
class Variation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'variations';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'id');
    }
}
```

Luego tengo un botón para duplicar:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.duplicate', $pro->id) }}"><i class="far fa-copy eye"></i></a>
```

Y la ruta:

```
Route::get('mi-cuenta/productos/duplicate/{id}', 'adminController@duplicate')->name('admin.duplicate');
```

Y por último el controlador donde lo duplico:

```
public function duplicate (Request $request, $id)
    {
        $producto = Product::findOrFail($id);
        $newProduct = $producto->replicate();

        foreach($producto->combinations as $combination)
        {
            $newProduct->combinations()->attach($combination);
        }

        $newProduct->push();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

He probado duplicarlo sin las relaciones y me lo duplica perfectamente, pero al poner que tambien haga las relaciones me devuelve esto:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::attach()
```

Comment: Hola @BetaM , he cambiado en los modelos de variations y combinations el `hasmany` por `belongsToMany` y en la query el `attach` por `detach` pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error pero con detach. Además tengo que hacer lo que el compañero dice en la respuesta?

Comment: Y alguna sugerencia? puedo hacer lo mismo pero haciendo la consulta con la `$id`??

Comment: Pues un producto puede tener muchas variaciones y combinaciones, variaciones puede tener más de una fila pero solo pertenecen a una id de producto y con combinaciones sucede lo mismo @BetaM

Comment: ok ok ahora entiendo, cuando consiga solucionarlo pongo la respuesta, gracias @BetaM

Comment: Exacto hay que duplicar del id del producto, el producto en si, las variaciones que tenga ese producto id y lo mismo con las combinaciones, gracias @BetaM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es importante notar que tanto:

- **`attach`**
- **`detach`**

Solo existen para la clase `BelongsToMany` por medio del *trait* `InteractsWithPivotTable`.

Dicho lo anterior, entonces la forma en que intentas no funcionará pues la clase `HasMany` no usa este *trait* y por eso el motivo de error.

Por otro lado debes tener en claro las relaciones que debes definir en cada modelo, puesto que tanto tu modelo `Product` y `Combination` poseen un `hasMany` cuando (*al menos con la información propuesta*) debería ser:

- Un producto *tiene muchas combinaciones*
- Una combinación *pertenece a un producto*

Y quedar así:

Modelo Product

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function combinations()
    {
        $this->hasMany(Combination::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Combination

```
class Combination extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Si seguimos lo antes expuesto, entonces el id del producto vive como llave foránea en la entidad `Combination`

**Ejemplo**

Si deseamos replicar un registro existente de la entidad `Combination` para tener mas de una vez el `product_id` con valor 1, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

- Obtén una única instancia del modelo `Combination` y asignalo como valor a una variable

  ```
  $oneCombination = Combination::findOrFail($id);
  ```
- Replicamos al modelo filtrado y lo asignamos a una variable:

  ```
  $replicatedCombination = $oneCombination->replicate();
  ```
- Finalmente registramos el modelo replicado de esta forma:

  ```
  Modelo::create([
      'clave1' => $replicatedCombination->valor1,
      'clave2' => $replicatedCombination->valor2,
      'clave3' => $replicatedCombination->valor3,
  ]);
  ```

**Extra**

Aunque el código que te expongo es *funcional*, puede que también quieras revisar el [apartado de la propia documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#replicating-models) donde expone que puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

- Encontramos un modelo por su id

  ```
  $modeloPorId = Modelo::findOrFail($id);
  ```
- Replicamos al modelo y lo asignamos a una variable

  ```
  $modeloReplicado = $modeloPorId->replicate();
  ```
- Finalmente *salvamos* el nuevo registro

  ```
  $modeloReplicado->save();
  ```

**Opcionalmente**.

Si quieres darle un valor personalizado a alguna de las propiedades del valor replicado, entonces puedes utilizar el método `fill`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @BetaM por la respuesta tan elaborada, luego a la noche lo pruebo y te comento.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias @BetaM

Comment: @Miguel te edité el aporte colocando un extra apoyado en lo que la propia documentación expone, si gustas revisarlo seguro también te es útil.

Comment: Ok! ahora lo reviso muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hace `replicate()` es crear una `non-existing instance`, por lo que primero debes realizar el `push()` o guardarlo antes de acceder a sus relaciones.

```
    $producto = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $newProduct = $producto->replicate();

    $newProduct->push();

    foreach($producto->combinations as $combination)
    {
        $newProduct->combinations()->attach($combination);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
```